# Can shoving someone be nonviolent?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to express a situation were someone is being forced/persuaded to move in a certain direction by another person, not in a violent, but  rather a humorous, way.

The word I'm thinking of using is shoved. I am however worried that it would be interpreted as violent and not, as intend, amusing.

Cartoony example:

> The man was shoved towards the department store by his enthusiastic spouse.

Can the word shoved be used without violent connotations? Is there a better word to use in the example above?

Comment: This is all just a matter of opinion. Personally, I don't see any significant connotations of "violence" in [a fellow who had blatantly shoved into the queue at a museum entrance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22blatantly+shoved+into+the+queue%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), just "violation" (of protocol, good manners).

Comment: ...and there's never likely to be any exhortation to violence if you're asked to [**Shove up and make room**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shove+up%22+%22make+room%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (on a church pew, for example, so more people can sit down).

Comment: This may be regional. For me, shoving into a queue would imply a level of violence.

Comment: @chasly: Like I said, it's really just a matter of opinion. But surely you wouldn't expect a violent response in the church pew context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would never expect to hear anyone say “Shove up and make room” in a church—far too colloquial and crude to be said in church. Even people who don’t believe in God at all (like me) would use more polite language in a church, like “Could you move over a bit? Make room for one more…”. Even if it’s just your living room couch and you’re talking to your annoying siblings, though, there is an element present of unwilling bustling and jostling to make room when you say “shove up”. Not violence as such, perhaps, but definite unwilling physical bumping.

Comment: @Janus: I haven't been in a church (except maybe as a tourist) for many decades, so I'm not necessarily clued up on what language I might be prepared to use there. But in similar "relatively formal" contexts I wouldn't exactly see the usage as "crude". Not in the same league as *Shift your asses*, say, which I probably wouldn't use unless it was a *very* informal gathering (or if I was *very very* drunk! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is one thing for someone to say *shove over*, which if done in a friendly-enough way, would be quite acceptable in church or anywhere (including, I feel sure, on the benches of the House of Commons). I also see nothing wrong with saying someone 'shoved in the queue'. It would not imply they did anything violent, merely impolite. But it is something altogether different to 'shove' someone, which inevitably suggests some level of violence, however minor.

Comment: Of course 'when push comes to shove' anything might be regarded as violent!

Comment: @WS": Until I just checked OED, I'd pretty much have taken it for granted that ***shove*** was etymologically related to ***shuffle***, but apparently that's not the case. Anyway, I certainly never intended to imply that ***shove*** *never* has any "violent" connotations - just that for me at least it doesn't *always* have them. But then again I seem to be one of a vanishing breed of Anglophones who don't always see sexual, sarcastic, or other overtones in a vast array of usages. Not because I'm completely unaware of them, but because if they're contextually irrelevant I "ignore" them.

Comment: Your example paints a vivid picture. I perceive no vehement intent; only that her desire to shop for bridesmaids dresses far exceeds his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been stated, "shove" does not necessarily imply violence, but does imply a sort of violation. I would suggest "The man was herded towards..." This captures the forceful intent by his spouse, without implying negative feelings.

```
Herd
 verb 
   1.(with reference to a group of people or animals) move in a particular direction.
```

Answer (score 8):

*[Hustle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hustle)* might work as an alternative to the violent implications of *shoved*, :

> verb
>
> 1 [WITH OBJECT] Push roughly; jostle:
>   *they were hissed and hustled as
>   they went in*
>
> 1.1 [WITH OBJECT AND ADVERBIAL OF DIRECTION] Force (someone) to move hurriedly or unceremoniously:
>   *I was hustled away to a cold cell*
>
> 1.2 [NO OBJECT, WITH ADVERBIAL OF DIRECTION] Push one’s way; bustle:
>   *Stockwell hustled into the penalty area*
>
> 2 [WITH OBJECT] informal , chiefly North American Obtain illicitly or
>   by forceful action:
>   *Linda hustled money from men she met*
>
> 2.1 (hustle someone into) Pressure someone into doing something:
>   *don’t be hustled into anything unless you really want to*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

Although both *hustle* and *shove* **can** denote the same sense of pushing, hustle can also connote a less violent compulsion. The context of the OP leaves the interpretation open, but welcomes the "gentler" sense of *hurried pressure*:

> *The man was **hustled** towards the department store by his enthusiastic spouse.*

---

The definition of *[shove](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shove)* is pretty straightforward:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1.0 Push (someone or something) roughly:
>   *police started pushing and shoving people down the street*
>
> [NO OBJECT]: *kids pushed, kicked, and shoved*
>
> 1.1 [NO OBJECT, WITH ADVERBIAL OF DIRECTION] Make one’s way by pushing someone or something:
>   *Woolley shoved past him*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

The operational definition of the OP is actually *[violent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/violent)*:

> adjective
>
> 1.0 Using or involving physical force intended to hurt, damage, or kill
>   someone or something:
>   *a violent confrontation with riot police*
>
> 1.1 **Law** Involving an unlawful exercise or exhibition of force.
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

At a strictly interpersonal level, it would not be *violence* if there was no intent to harm, but there can always be two interpretations of intent. The person shoving interprets their own intentions objectively, while the one being shoved interprets those intentions subjectively. The legal definition comes into play when the person being shoved feels violated enough to ask the police to intervene. Even then the police may just show up to cool things down.

There is no *legal violence* in *shoving* if both parties agreed to rough each other up--including a gradual escalation in conflict. The players in a rugby or American football game, are often *shoving* each other *violently*, but the participants find some pleasure in exchanging these harmful actions to test their mettle. In ice hockey players can actually have a grand fist fight, while the spectators cheer them on, but they each spend 5 minutes in the penalty box as a token nod to the fact that we still disapprove of *violence* in general.

In the context of the OP, the connotations would be a matter of divergent opinion. Was the action of shoving actually harmful? Does the woman intend to *violate* the man's freedom, dignity or physical wellbeing? Does the man feel *violated*? Have they agreed to enjoy this shoving process on the way to the store? The interpretation of any third party would be highly subjective.

Comment: Since this Question seems to have majored on alternatives, perhaps you should lead with hustle?

Answer (score 7):

***nudge***
: to touch or push (someone or something) gently
: to encourage (someone) to do something
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nudge

Comment: 'nudge' was my first thought too. It depends whether the action is momentary or continuous.

Comment: If it’s more continuous and a bit more adamant, _bustle_ would be another good option.

Comment: This is the best answer. You should put the word nudge in bold or something (use the bold tool in the editor, or add two **'s both before and after it)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest "propelled" or "steered". If you shove someone it implies unwelcome force.

Comment: Also 'guided' or 'urged.'

Answer (score 0):

The only way that shoving a person could not be of violent intent would be when it was due to accident, emergency (thank you Chris) or gross boorishness. It implies a strong physical contact. Shoving an object is not necessarily violent, but indicates that not much care is being taken of the object.

The word you are looking for is probably **nudged** per Gary's answer. If the woman shoved her husband toward the department store, she must have been a rather violent womant and he must have been a severly henpecked man.

Comment: Would you regard "shoving him out of the way of the approaching bus" as violent?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word *[chivvy](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chivy&submit.x=38&submit.y=25)* (or sometimes *chivy*)

> To maneuver or secure gradually: "had spent two weeks chivvying this division toward combat readiness" (Tom Clancy)

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Not necessarily involving humor, but a gradual urging.

Answer (score 0):

I love Mazura's comment, haha! I would give an upvote to chasly for "propelled" or "steered" if I could (but as a newbie, not yet allowed) with a thumbs-up to Elijah's "guided" or "urged" as well. I would like to add **push** as my choice for a word that fits comfortably between the more forceful "shove," and the  too-timid "nudge."

Comment: On second thought, I think **PULLED** works even better in the cartoony example given!

Comment: It would surely take some inordinate effort to infer any kind of violence there.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen adjectives used in front of the word "shoved" to describe the event you are talking about like gently or lovingly or jokingly to soften the word.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the verb "border-collied" as this is amusing and helps to visualize a person gently and relentlessly being herded like a sheep.

Answer (score -1):

might I suggest "Nudge" or "Elbow" as non-violent replacements for the harsher-sounding "Shove"

Comment: Hi Kitsune and welcome to ELU! Those are good suggestions, but you should consider adding their definitions to your answer.